# Print total users

Tags: discord.py

When using the button I want the button to print the total number of users, but it always says '0' please help

```
       client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)
        
        def test(client):
            print(str(len(client.guilds)))
        
        async def open_window():
            window=tk.Tk()
            window.geometry("500x300") 
            g = Button(window, text='test', command=test)
            g.place(x=250, y=150)
            window.mainloop()
        
        client.loop.create_task(open_window())
        client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache is loaded when the bot is ready, you will need to wait until the bot is ready

And for total users, use `len()` on `Bot.users`

Below is the revised code:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)

def test(client):
    print(str(len(client.users)))

async def open_window():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    window=tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("500x300") 
    g = Button(window, text='test', command=test)
    g.place(x=250, y=150)
    window.mainloop()

client.loop.create_task(open_window())
client.run(TOKEN)
```